# How do I add more level colors to the SEQ website

Tags: seq-logging

The SEQ instance we are using only has 3 level color distinctions -

*Errors = red

Warnings = yellow

Everything else = no color*

According to the following link, there should be an option under "Settings > Theme" to add custom CSS which I could use to add more colors -

https://docs.datalust.co/discuss/582cbe0d05c3211b007009a1

I am not finding that option.

Does anyone know if that option can still be available? And how to make it available?
Or is there any other good way to add custom CCS to SEQ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is still available. Look for Settings -> Instance.

Changes to instance styles affect all users on the server, so this setting is only available to users in the *Administrator* role. If you do change it make sure you test your changes with all of the possible themes that individual users may have selected for themselves.

[image: Seq Instance Settings]